# Using base classes and method overriding to write neater code

Tags: c#, oop

I've heard about how base classes and method overriding can be combined to eliminate code reuse/write neater code.

Is there an example available of how this can be done (in C#)?

Thanks

Comment: eliminate code reuse? Quite the opposite, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you factor out common functionality from a set of classes that you have created and put that functionality into a base class.  Then, when each class inherits from the base class, they receive that functionality (or can choose to override it and provide their own implementation).  The code that provides the functionality remains in the base class, in one place, instead of across your set of classes.

[Here is a good discussion](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/Inheritance.aspx) on that as well as how polymorphism fits in.  There are many [good books](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_ss_gw?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=object+oriented+programming+c%23) on this subject.

Answer (score 0):

I think a good way to learn about the power of polymorphism is to take a look at Bob Martin's [SOLID principles of OOD](http://www.butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod) and also to study design patterns and their use of polymorphism to provide solutions to common problems. I recommend [Head First Design Patterns](http://www.amzn.com/0596007124) for the later.